# Search in R dataframe with more than one attribute in expression

Tags: r, subset

I've created the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                 var2=c("f","e","d","c","b","a"), 
                 var3=c("b",1,3,"f","d","5"))

row.names(df) <- c("val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5", "val6")

     var1 var2 var3
val1    1    f    b
val2    2    e    1
val3    3    d    3
val4    4    c    f
val5    5    b    d
val6    6    a    5
```

I've created a vector too:

```
variables <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
```

When I type `df[,variables]` R prints the columns associated with attributes defined in `variables`.

My purpose is to filter in the dataframe like:

```
df[variables==3, ]
```

And expect to see in the prompt all rows which are equal to 3 in any of these attributes. For example, with the dataframe defined above:

```
df[variables=="d", ]

      var1 var2 var3
 val3    3    d    3
 val5    5    b    d
```

¿How could I achieve that?

Note: I know that defining the `variables` elements as strings R is gonna compare them as strings and it won't run. I tried the following too:

```
df[df[,variables]==3, variables]
```

But R returns only one row and stranger things like:

```
     var1 var2 var3
val3    3    d    3
NA     NA <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: That's not right. If I type `df[1:nrow(df) == 5, ]` it shoul return me the rows 5 and 6, but it only returns the fifth.

Comment: Maybe so `df[rowSums(df == 5) >= 1, ]`

Comment: Done. Thanks @markus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df[rowSums(df == 5) >= 1, ]
```

In the first part `df == 5` looks for values that are equal to 5 and returns a matrix with the same dimensions as `df`.

```
df == 5
#      var1  var2  var3
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

When you call `rowSums(df == 5)` you get a numeric vector in return.

```
rowSums(df == 5)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Now you check wheter any of these values is greater or equal to `1` by `rowSums(df == 5) >= 1` and use the result to filter for the desired rows.

```
df[rowSums(df == 5) >= 1, ]
#  var1 var2 var3
#5    5    b    d
#6    6    a    5
```